# unexpected error: Trezor returned failure: code=99, message=Firmware error

Tags: trezor, cli

Monero CLI Monero 'Boron Butterfly' (v0.14.1.2-release) with Trezor model T
Trezor Firmware: 2.1.4 / Bridge 2.0.27

I was really happy with CLI trezor wallet but unfortunately it seems I cannot transfer funds:

-monerod running synced, open cli, refresh wallet
-use the transfer   command. 
-as expected the cli indicates "device requires attention"
-confirm on device. Device indicates "generating outputs 2/2" etc as expected
-CLI throws the error

In this case I'm sending to a new generated address in the same account.
Regular wallets (no HW) don't have the issue.
It's latest version of cli. Trezor has newer version but nothing in the changelog mentions monero.

How to solve?

Comment: This bug started occurring after the latest firmware upgrade(s). The current recommendation is to downgrade the firmware such that you can continue to properly use Monero in conjunction with a Trezor device. See: https://www.reddit.com/r/monerosupport/comments/d6dcms/cant_send_xmr_from_monero_gui_with_trezor_model_t/f14f7qn/ (full thread will show multiple people reporting a similar issue).

Comment: Thanks for recognizing the bug and I'm not the only one. I'm looking for alternatives to downgrading. I'd like to have the recent updates but none of them mention anything monero related https://wiki.trezor.io/Firmware_changelog and support ofcourse point to the third party wallet (xmr cli) software, was any one able to look at the cause or maybe some fix is on the way?

Comment: You're welcome. It could be that another change in the firmware inadvertently broke the Monero integration. I genuinely think downgrading is the best option currently. As far as we know, the Trezor team is investigating the issue (an email was sent to inform them).

Comment: Is monero-trezor integration still broken in newer firmware? Would like to find out is everyone with xmr on trezor having the bug or should I experiment? What type of users can send without issue? Starting to think where do we go from here as we can't stick to old firmware forever (trezor is multi-currency, fixes stuff regularly, adds new features, what if trezor does an important fix today etc)

Comment: As far as I know, a bug fix has not yet been released. Thus, the current recommendation to downgrade the firmware is still applicable. I do expect a fix to be released relatively soon though.

Comment: The issue has been fixed in firmware v2.1.7, see: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/dm0zqx/trezor_transaction_failure_code99_message/f4wia95/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Trezor's CTO, the issue has been fixed in firmware v2.1.7:

> This is already fixed. Install firmware 2.1.7 from https://beta-wallet.trezor.io

**Source:** https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/dm0zqx/trezor_transaction_failure_code99_message/f4wia95/

Comment: Ah yes this solves the issue thanks for the support. Monero fan is happy again.